# ASP.NET how to Render a control to HTML?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have any ASP.NET control.  I want the HTML string how to do I get the HTML string of the control?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
public string RenderControlToHtml(Control ControlToRender)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
    ControlToRender.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The StringWriter and HtmlTextWriter both implement IDisposable, so you might want to wrap them in a using() {} block.  Also, it might be useful to make this an extension method of 'Control', so you can call it from an instance member.

Comment: @David, how did you end up with render an ascx file to html? I tried above method, but always get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", saying the user control I am referencing is not an instance. How should we use it in windows form or console application?

Comment: The default StringWriter() constructor creates a new string builder, so the first two lines can be replaced with just System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

Comment: This always gave me an empty string. However, a7drew's solution worked like charme.

Comment: I pass new Controls.sidebar() to the function, but I get empty string, although the control renders html when run inline.

Comment: this will not work unless control is part of the page.

Answer (score 15):

Accepted answer by `David Basarab` will not work if control is not part of the page. `a7drew`'s answer seems unnecessary complex - no need in `Context` or `Server.Execute`.

```
private string RenderControl()
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (var stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
    using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stWriter))
    {
        var p = new Page();
        var ctrl = (YourControl)p.LoadControl("~/controls/building blocks/YourControl.ascx");
        ctrl.Visible = true;

        // do your own init logic if needed

        p.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        ctrl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! By the way, in my testing, the `ctrl.Visible = true;` line seems not to be needed.

Comment: Thank you! I had a method that worked but for a service but not when called from an API. This works!

Comment: I see that `ctrl.Visible = true;` as an ensurance / failsafe. In my case, the control had @Visible="false"@ in markup, determining it to be rendered as an empty string.

Answer (score 6):

If your control is a web user control, this is how you can get to the HTML it emits from another page or handler:

```
public void GetHtmlFromMySweetControl(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpRequest httpRequest = context.Request;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = context.Response;

    string foo = httpRequest["foo"];

    Page pageHolder = new Page();
    string path = "~/usercontrols/MySweetControl.ascx";
    MySweetControl ctrl = (MySweetControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
    ctrl.BindProducts(foo);
    pageHolder.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    context.Server.Execute(pageHolder, sw, false);
    httpResponse.Write(sw.ToString());
}
```

Comment: When I try this, the HTML rendered out is different than what would normally appear on the page.  For instance, an asp:Panel with an  GroupingText attribute.  The value of the  GroupingText attribute is rendered now as a fieldset and legend.  This is not desirable...  its like the UserControl is being rendered under some different kind of mode....  completely different HTML...  :(

Comment: Nice! I did not even know this was possible! This allows very efficient ways of caching content! Thanks a lot!