# Get the HTML rendered by ASP.NET control in Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I want to call the corresponding html inside a Panel in code behind. How can I do that?

I have this

```
<asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server">
    // other asp.net controls and html stuffs here.
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to get the HTML equivalent of `MyPanel` and all of its contents in my code behind say in PageLoad or some methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925/asp-net-how-to-render-a-control-to-html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Does RenderControl() not work?

Create an instance of your control and then call RenderControl() on it. Of course this implies that your panel is in a UserControl

**example from comments:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb); 
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw); 
ctrl.RenderControl(hw); 
var html = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: but the return type of RenderControl() is void.. I need to get the HTML equivalent as a string or an object.

Comment: You pass in a TextWriter to the RenderControl() method. When the method returns, you have your html in the TextWriter

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    var html = sb.ToString();

Comment: Where ctrl is the instance of your UserControl

Comment: What if I don't want my control to appear on the page (i.e. not visible)

Comment: The StringWriter default constructor creates a new string builder. Example could be simplified to-
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(); 
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw); 
ctrl.RenderControl(hw); 
var html = tw.ToString();

Comment: This always gave me an empty string. However, a7drew's solution here worked like charme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925/asp-net-how-to-render-a-control-to-html (I was calling via web service, maybe that was the reason why this solution did not work?)

Comment: This is helping me b/c I'm receiving the must be in webform error, if your asp.net control contains any button controls, etc:  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122006-1.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work if (for example) an element like a <div> was added to the panel dynamically via javascript. The dynamically added content doesn't appear in the result.

Answer (score 3):

@Shiv Kumar's answer is correct. However you don't need the `StringBuilder` for this.

```
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(); 
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw); 
ctrl.RenderControl(hw); 
var html = tw.ToString();
```

This also works