# Get The Actual HTML code for a control from client side

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to get the actual HTML text for the control from the client browser because some of the info in this control don't show on the sever side special the "Style". So How can get the whole HTML text for a control?

Comment: You can move to asp.net mvc and forget about controls altogether! It's heaven! :-)

Comment: what about `Control.Attributes["style"]`? what is the need of getting the style attribute in server side?

Comment: @Murali I tried but it is empty

Comment: @kartal, does the control/page has a viewstate enabled?

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925/asp-net-how-to-render-a-control-to-html

Regards,
Uros

Comment: @kartal, try using control.InnerHTML property

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" OnChange="tbOnChange();" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tbOnChange() {
            var tb1 = document.getElementById('tb1');
            alert(tb1.value);
        }
    </script>
```

EDIT: For get style in C#

ASP page:

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" runat="server" style="color:Red;" />
```

C# page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var style = tb1.Style;
    }
```

Regards

k.