# Render PlaceHolder within li tags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-placeholder

I've got the next situation: within an ITemplate object I'm rendering a Repeater with `<li>` elements inside, normally it's done like this:

```
Dim literalControl as new LiteralControl
literalControl = "<li>blah blah</li>"
container.Controls.Add(literalControl)
```

But at one point I need to add a PlaceHolder returned by another function which serves other purposes, not only this repeater and I get something like this:

```
Dim literalControl as new LiteralControl
Dim plTable As PlaceHolder

literalControl = "<li>blah blah</li>"
MyObject.Render(AComplexObect, plTable)

container.Controls.Add(literalControl)
container.Controls.Add(plTable)
```

This works just fine but elements in placehoder stay *outside* `<li>` tag, I want it inside. `plTable` has many elements of different types inside, so I loop converting it's content to Literal or LiteralControl throws error as not all elements can be converted to these types.

What alternatives do I have?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```vb
Dim literalControl As New LiteralControl
Dim plTable As PlaceHolder
Dim swWriter As New StringWriter
Dim htwWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(swWriter)

MyObject.Render(AComplexObect, plTable)
MyObject.RenderControl(htwWriter)

literalControl.Text = "<li>" & swWriter.ToString() & "</li>"

container.Controls.Add(literalControl)
```

Comment: I don't really get it, how do I implement `MyObject.RenderControl(htwWriter)`? thanx

Comment: This assumes `MyObject` is a control. All controls have a `RenderControl` method you can call on them to get the HTML. It's basically the same code found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925/asp-net-how-to-render-a-control-to-html