# Debugging an incorrectly rendered control

Tags: asp.net, debugging, stream

I'm trying to debug a weird issue where a control is being rendered with multiple (different) id attributes.  I believe something is manually adding the incorrect id, but I'm having issues figuring out when, and `myControl.Attributes` is empty.

Is it possible to set a breakpoint midway through `Page_Render` and read what has currently been written to the Output stream?

Note that `Response.OutputStream.CanRead` is false.

Or better yet, is there a way to view the string that would be rendered by a control at a given point in time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET how to Render a control to HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925/asp-net-how-to-render-a-control-to-html)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".