# How to get HTML output of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu in CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution containing an ASP.NET WebForms Website and a MVC 5 Application. The WebForms project contains a `MenuControl` for main navigation. I need to have the same menu in the MVC Project as well.

I tried to get the html of the menu using the solution mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931/1300140 without any success. It is throwing an error saying "Control 'ctl03' of type 'Menu' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

How can I get the HTML output of the Menu? Also, is there any better way to achieve  what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

First create a div (or any other asp.net control) with tag `runat=server` so you can reach it from code behind.

then a little jquery and done.

html:

```
 <div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("myDiv").html($("#yourMenuIdHere").html());
    });
```

code behind:

```
var divContent= myDiv.InnerHtml;
```

so you got everything in divContent variable. you can hide your `myDiv` on pageload if you want. let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I was trying to do this as a last resort as I will have to wait for a request/postback.