# Is it possible to StreamWrite the DataList Result to make an HTML file? (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Here is my example code on what I am trying to do, can you give an example syntax to make this possible?

The query select will run to show data on datalist and after that if button is click the results will be written to an HTML file.

**Page Load**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DataList();
                }
            }
```

**Data List**

```
public void DataList()
               {
                 String testcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ToString();
                    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(testcon );
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From ExampleTable";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
                    DataList1.DataBind();

                    con.Close();
            }
```

**Button Click**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream((path + "\\Sample.html"), FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    w.WriteLine("<html>");
                    w.WriteLine("</head>");
                    w.WriteLine("<body>");
                    w.WriteLine("DataList(ItemTemplate)");
                    w.WriteLine("</body>");
                    w.WriteLine("</html>");
                }
                LabelDisplay.Text = "File Successfully Created @ " + ((path + "\\Sample.html"));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is [RenderControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925/asp-net-how-to-render-a-control-to-html) what you are looking for?

Comment: if RenderControl can get the HTML string of DataList, then that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, that would do it

Comment: but, will this work if I StreamWrite the DataList to become an HTML file?

Comment: You can get the html in a string like in the link I gave you.

Comment: I didn't read closely. DataList is an asp.net control but that's not what you meant. Apologies, disregard what I said.

Comment: can you give an example syntax to get the HTML string of DataList? I can't seem to understand the answers posted on the link that you gave me. I mean where will put the <asp:DataList id="DataList1"> Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session["DataList"] = ds.tables[0];

You can copy paste the below method which will convert the datatable to the html string.

```
protected string ExportDatatableToHtml(DataTable dt)  
{  
    StringBuilder strHTMLBuilder = new StringBuilder();  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<html >");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<head>");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</head>");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<body>");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='lightyellow' style='font-family:Garamond; font-size:smaller'>");  

    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<tr >");  
    foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)  
    {  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<td >");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName);  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</td>");  

    }  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</tr>");  


    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)  
    {  

    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<tr >");  
    foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)  
    {  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("<td >");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</td>");  

    }  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</tr>");  
    }  

    //Close tags.  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</table>");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</body>");  
    strHTMLBuilder.Append("</html>");  

    string Htmltext = strHTMLBuilder.ToString();  

    return Htmltext;  
}
```

After this method, You can call this method and convert to html file as below

```
 string content = ExportDatatableToHtml((DataTable)Session["DataList"]);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\sample.html", contents);
```

If my post helps to solve your question, kindly check the green tick and upward this answer

Comment: You are assigning the dataset to the datalist1.datasource right. In that place, you can assign the dataset table in the session variable like in the my updated answer.

Comment: Check and revert if need assistance. if solves your question , check the green tick :-)

Comment: I got this error... when I put the Session["DataList"] below da.Fill(ds)

'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'tables' and no extension method 'tables' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you check the condition like this 
if(ds != null)
{
If(ds.Tables.count > 0)
{
   Session["DataList"] = ds.Tables[0];
}
}

Comment: tables - T should be in capital letter (Tables). I updated my previous answer

Comment: it says 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'tables'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168110/discussion-between-vivek-ramasamy-and-christian-quirante).